# mysql: group surrounding records by same field value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table with a following structure and data:

```
id | type | title
--------------------------
1  | 1    | test 1
2  | 1    | test 2
3  | 2    | test 3
4  | 2    | test 4
5  | 1    | test 5
```

I need to group neighbor rows with the same `type` field values.

So the result should be like:

```
type |
------
1    |
2    |
1    |
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `select * from table group by type`

Comment: So you want to coalesce rows where the current row has the same type as the previous row, ordered by id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick.. using user defined variables.

```
SELECT 
    type 
FROM(
    SELECT 
        type,
        if(@a = type, @b, @b := @b + 1) as grouping_col,
        @a := type
    FROM testing
    JOIN (select @a := 1, @b := 0) as temp
) as t
GROUP BY grouping_col;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18bc07/1) to play with

Comment: but if it is not hard for you, can you explain this query for me please?

Comment: @dimaninc sure thing.. so basically it does a row by row calculation... i say if the type of the last row (stored in @a) is = to the type of the current row, then dont change my grouping column value so that they will be grouped... if that statement failes @b (the grouping column value) is incremented so that it will increase by 1 for every new instance of a type. run the inside query to see the exact result of every row.

Comment: @dimaninc look at this SQL fiddle... look at the value of the column i call `grouping_col` .. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/18bc07/2 ---- that should help you understand it better ;)

Comment: ...and sqlfiddle seems to be playing up

Comment: @JohnRuddell oh i think i got it. but i still don't under stand what is the line `JOIN (select @a := 1, @b := 0) as temp` needed for?

Comment: @dimaninc that JOIN is just creating the variables.. I'm basically making two variables that have the datatype int

Comment: @JohnRuddell that join sets the initial values to them? thanks a lot! now i think i totally understood the query!

Comment: @dimaninc yes it just sets an inital value to them and says what the datatype is... if i was going to set a variable to a string then I would make it like this `JOIN (select @temp := "") as test` setting it to an empty string so that its the same datatype :)

Comment: @Strawberry this has nothing to do with the id... its only looking at the type column. it is just doing a comparison of the previous row's type to the current rows... the assumption made is that the data pulled out is in the correct order as laid out in the table.

Comment: My mistake - but that's bad news. Without an ORDER BY clause (but with an INDEX on say, (title,type)) this will return the wrong result.

Comment: it will return the result that comes from the database. so as long as the OP doesn't change his database it will return in the correct order.... if it is changed then there will need to be an ORDER BY added to the query.

Comment: That IS true in practice, but it is not true according to the documentation - just saying

Comment: .... when you select from a table it has a default order. and then if you add indexes and other things it will change that order. I don't know what the OP has set up on his table currently (i just have what he posted).. but whatever that is it pulls it out in this order. so thats how I wrote the query. IF something changes to the database and the order is changed its obvious that you would need to add an order by statement. not sure why you're making a big deal about this considering the two cents were already thrown in about order by.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way - although a solution using variables will scale better...

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY 
 ,type INT NOT NULL 
 ,title VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1,1,'test 1'),
 (3,1,'test 2'),
 (4,2,'test 3'),
 (7,2,'test 4'),
 (9,1,'test 5');

 SELECT * FROM my_table;
 +----+------+--------+
 | id | type | title  |
 +----+------+--------+
 |  1 |    1 | test 1 |
 |  3 |    1 | test 2 |
 |  4 |    2 | test 3 |
 |  7 |    2 | test 4 |
 |  9 |    1 | test 5 |
 +----+------+--------+  

 SELECT a.id start
      , MIN(c.id) End 
      , a.type
   FROM 
      ( SELECT x.*,COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.id <= x.id GROUP BY x.id) a
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT x.*,COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.id <= x.id GROUP BY x.id) b 
     ON b.type = a.type
    AND b.rank = a.rank - 1
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT x.*,COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.id <= x.id GROUP BY x.id) c 
     ON c.type = a.type
    AND c.rank >= a.rank 
   LEFT 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT x.*,COUNT(*) rank FROM my_table x JOIN my_table y ON y.id <= x.id GROUP BY x.id) d 
     ON d.type = a.type
    AND d.rank = c.rank + 1
  WHERE b.id IS NULL 
    AND c.id IS NOT NULL
    AND d.id IS NULL
  GROUP 
     BY a.id; 
+-------+------+------+
| start | End  | type |
+-------+------+------+
|     1 |    3 |    1 |
|     4 |    7 |    2 |
|     9 |    9 |    1 |
+-------+------+------+
```